# ASP .Net Core Razor asp-page-handler not working

Tags: asp.net-core, razor

I created a brand new ASP .NET Core Razor web application and when I post with a custom asp-page-handler, OnPost() is hit, not OnPostContact(). This is such a simple form so there must be something simple I have overlooked.

Definitely a problem with my taghelpers, as I can get a model value to display like this:

```
@Model.FirstName
```

But not like this:

```
<input asp-for="FirstName" type="text" class="form-control" />
```

Here's the code, I can't see what's wrong here:

Index.cshmtl:

```
    <form method="post" asp-page-handler="Contact">
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly"></div>
        <span asp-validation-for="FirstName"></span>
        <input type="text" asp-for="FirstName" />
        <button type="submit">Send</button>
    </form>
```

Index.cshtml.cs:

```
public IActionResult OnPost()
{
    return Page();
}

public IActionResult OnPostContact()
{
    return Page();
}
```

_ViewImports.cshtml:

```
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
```

Comment: Did you try to remove   @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

Comment: Without @Html.AntiForgeryToken() I get a 400 error

Comment: In general you don't need `@Html.AntiForgeryToken`, it is added automatically. And I do put `asp-page-handler="Contact"` inside submit button tags and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it was something stupid I was missing. There was a div tag further up in my page that had an extra quote and it somehow caused my tags not to work properly... an hour of time wasted.

```
<div class="container" data-aos="fade-up" ">
```